# clicking on page title

Tags: posts, title

In the website I'm looking for something so that I can disable clicking titles in category posts.

Just want them to be a simple text not a link one

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Just remove the link from the theme. But you know that probably ... what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

usually the code that makes a link to a title in WordPress looks something like this

```
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><php the_title(); ?></a>
```

if you were to change it to this

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

it would only display the title. It would remove the link. Does that answer your question?

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Try posting your code

Comment: which code? function.php?

Comment: The code that you are changing. If its not working, that means you are changing the wrong file.